# Place Buttons in Swift in Fibonacci spiral

Tags: ios, swift, math, fibonacci

I would like to place 3 `UIButtons` so the curve matches the `Fibonacci-Graph` like this:

[image]

The first `button` (bottom left corner) is set. The other two are moved there with `transformerOptimus = transformerOptimus.translatedBy(x: anyValue, y: anyValue)`.

The question is what I have to calculate so it is on the circle. Is there a general formula that can be applied here?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to define the angle separating the buttons. Here it looks like π/10.
Now you already have the radius, for the first circle it's 8 units * pixel par unit
and then you can use the formula to transform polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates. [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

```
x = radius * cos(alpha)
y = radius * sin(alpha)
```

Note that alpha is the angle in radian between 0 and 2π starting on the right of the center and going anticlockwise. So the first button on your exemple (the lowest) has an angle of π. the second an angle of π-π/10 , ...